# Error of using tfidf as the input of method 'model.fit()' in package lda

Tags: python, tf-idf, lda

I was using package LDA in python to analysis the topics in documents, it's ok when I use term frequency as the input of method 
 'model.fit()',however, there is always a error, saying that '***TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe***'******',using Tfidf as the input of method 'model.fix()' in the package LDA.
The code is as follows:(Every line in papers.txt is specific terms as the representation of each document)

```
corpus = []
for line in open('papers.txt','r').readlines():
  corpus.append(line.strip())
vectorizer =  CountVectorizer()
#tf-idf
transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus))
analyze = vectorizer.build_analyzer()
weight = tfidf.toarray() 
words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
years = getYears()
#import lda
model = lda.LDA(n_topics=30,n_iter=500,random_state = 1)
model.fit(np.asarray(weight))
topic_word = model.topic_word_
doc_topic = model.doc_topic_
```

It seems that package LDA's method 'model.fit()' can only receive a matrix with the type of integer, not float? I have checked the documentation of package lda(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lda), unfortunately, there is no specific discussion about the  detaills. Does anyone had met the same problem? How do you fix these? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the np array first

`model.fit(np.asarray(weight))` should become `model.fit(np.asarray(weight).astype(int))`

Comment: Thanks, one thing should be mentioned that the td-idf  are float value, which is usually less than 1 in my case, if I transform the float value into integer, the program will work, however ,will cause a greater trouble because there will be a lot of zeros and the difference (weight) between terms will be ignored,  which means the LDA method will not work, because we transform a lot of weight values into zero. I was considering that may be the lda package can only accept integers such as term frequency?